# why eldoc mode makes emacs use 100% cpu?

Tags: emacs, elisp

when i use eldoc,i add this to .emacs:

```
 (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
 (add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
 (add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
```

and then when i use emacs,the emacs will use 100% cpu and it stucks.
but when i delete this code in .emacs,the emacs works.

anyone has idea about this?Or how to debug the problem.

Or anyother way to substitute for the eldoc mode

Comment: Which version of Emacs and for which platform? (`C-u M-x version`) Does this happen when this is the *only* thing in your .emacs file? (If not, you'll want to try to track down the conflict.)

Answer (score 4):

You can run `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit RET`, then `C-g` will bring up a backtrace of what it is doing at the moment.  You can update the question with the result if you can't figure out the problem at that point.

An alternate way is to comment out the rest of your `.emacs` file (everything except `eldoc-mode` stuff) and then uncomment pieces of it and see where things break.  It's probably the interaction of eldoc with something else since eldoc has always worked great for me.

You might also want to check the value of `eldoc-documentation-function` to see if it's set to something weird.

Comment: thank you.I found it,i delete the eldoc-highlight function from the emacswiki,then everything goes well.Another question,how to let emacs start use a special file,perhaps i want a emacs.fast,not the common .emacs?

Comment: That is another question, but you can do `emacs -q -l FILE`.  The `-q` means don't load an init file, and the `-l` means to load the file `FILE`.  You can find these and other options in `man emacs` or a complete list in `info emacs`.  You might also consider byte-compiling your `.emacs`, but that is a different question entirely and there should information on the internet that's not too hard to find.

Comment: Thank you,i just can't find this -l File,other aspect i know